# Simplifying Nested Query Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to simplify below nested query? there are some performances issues related to this query

```
    select
    t.GroupName as ProviderName,
    t.GroupName as Groupname,
    t.idPriceGroup,
    sum(t.fixed_value) as fixed_value,
    avg(isnull(t.percent_value, 0)) as percent_value, 
    isnull(sum(amount), 0) as amount, 
    sum(case when Include2SpecTotal = 1 then isnull(amount,0) else 0 end) as AmountSpecial,
    isnull(sum(bonus_total), 0) as bonus_total,
    isnull(sum(bonus_landlord), 0) as bonus_landlord,
    sum(case when Include2SpecTotal = 1 then isnull(bonus_landlord,0) else 0 end) as bonus_landlordSpecial
from
    (
        SELECT 
            ISNULL(dbo.fn_GetProviders_str(p.idLocalize, 'EN'), 'Test Service') as ProviderName, 
            idSupplier,
            r.idProvider,
            alias,
            isnull(amount, 0) amount, 
            isnull(bonus_total, 0) bonus_total,
            isnull(bonus_landlord, 0) bonus_landlord, 
            (SELECT idPriceGroup FROM dbo.fn_GetPricelistGroupForProvider(r.idSupplier, r.alias)) as idPriceGroup, 
            (SELECT [name] FROM dbo.fn_GetPricelistGroupForProvider(r.idSupplier, r.alias)) as GroupName, 
            (SELECT Include2SpecTotal FROM dbo.fn_GetPricelistGroupForProvider(r.idSupplier, r.alias)) as Include2SpecTotal, 
            isnull(fixed_value, 0)
            fixed_value,
            isnull(percent_value, 0) percent_value  
        FROM ReportTurnoverItems r
            left join providers p ON r.idSupplier = p.idProviderExternal AND r.idProvider = p.idProvider
        WHERE CHARINDEX(',' + cast(idReportTurnover as varchar) + ',', + ',' + @idReportTurnover+',') > 0
    ) t 
group by
    t.GroupName,
    t.idPriceGroup,
    t.Include2SpecTotal
order by
    avg(isnull(t.percent_value, 0)) desc,
    t.GroupName,
    t.idPriceGroup
```

Comment: Just by the way, for the sake of readability I advise to not mix uppercase SQL statements (such as `SELECT`) with lowercase (such as `group by`).

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow 
will take care of this

Comment: Could you give some more details around what the CHARINDEX is doing in the filter. I reckon should be able to get some easy improvement there, but can't quite tell what it's actually doing

Comment: Another potential performance killer is the function you are calling for each row {fn_GetPricelistGroupForProvider}.

Comment: @LJ01  truly, all these stuff is coming from some legacy code. My problem is I can't throw this query and I must have to fix to use it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling the function several times, you should do this:

```
select
    ....
    PGP.idPriceGroup, 
    PGP.name,
    PGP.Include2SpecTotal
    ...
FROM 
    ReportTurnoverItems r
    left join providers p ON r.idSupplier = p.idProviderExternal AND r.idProvider = p.idProvider
    outer apply dbo.fn_GetPricelistGroupForProvider(r.idSupplier, r.alias) PGP
```

Guessing that fn_GetPricelistGroupForProvider is a multi statement function, so you should look into turning it to an inline function.

Other problem of course is this:

```
WHERE CHARINDEX(',' + cast(idReportTurnover as varchar) + ',', + ',' + @idReportTurnover+',') > 0
```

SQL Server will not use any index for that -- and this looks like you have designed your database in a wrong way, that you have a list of values in a single field.

To be sure what the actual problem is, you should look into `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` and using `set statistics io on` -- but remember statistics io output does not show I/O happening inside functions.

Answer (score 3):

There can be multiple ways to do that.

- For checking the performance you need to run query with individual joins and find which join is causing the problem and work on that.
- I see you have used function, Try to comment those and see if you are getting any performance improvements. If yes you can look for integrating the function logic using join etc..
- Keep order by if its really required.
- You can move your sub query part to a CTE and see if anything is getting improved.

Comment: I would like to suggest that the functions is perhaps the most likely cause of the problem, so could go first?
   +1 for thorough answer